# How to rename all files and add image size to file name

Tags: files, rename, image-manipulation, exif, exiv2

I can't make this work. I have a lot of images and i want to rename his name and append image size to name using `exiv2`

`exiv2 pr *` prints all info about file

```
# exiv2 pr 9b523e5a002268fe5067a928
File name       : 9b523e5a002268fe5067a928
File size       : 356433 Bytes
MIME type       : image/jpeg
Image size      : 1920 x 1200
```

Now i want rename my file to look like

```
9b523e5a002268fe5067a928_1920x1200.jpeg
```

I already make something like this

```
exiv2 pr * | grep "Image " | awk -F':' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ //g'
```

It gives me the image size, but how do i extend this to get the image MIME type to get the .jpeg correct ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use exiftool instead:

```
exiftool -ext '' '-filename<%f_${ImageSize}.${FileType}' .
```

Would rename all the images in the current directory (`.`).

Comment: Flexibility of this Exiftool command is so power full. It looks like i don`t need any other tool anymore for many of my actions.

Comment: Nice! I had a slightly different usecase and used `exiftool -ext '*' '-filename<%f_${ImageSize}.%le'` to get lowercase extensions and apply to images with any extension.